# STM32F107 Clock configuration and USART problem

Tags: stm32

My old program (USART section) worked with a 25Mhz external crystal perfectly. I have changed my external crystal to 8 Mhz and multiplied it 8 to have a 64Mhz SYSClock. My timers, PWM and other sections work fine but my USART with 115200 baud rate doesn't work( it sends fault characters). I need to know what my problem is.

`void CLOCK(void){`

```
RCC_DeInit();   
RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
while(RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp()==ERROR);

FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(FLASH_PrefetchBuffer_Enable);   
FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);  

RCC_PLL2Cmd(DISABLE);

RCC_PLLCmd(DISABLE);
RCC_PREDIV1Config(RCC_PREDIV1_Source_HSE,RCC_PREDIV1_Div1); 
RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_PREDIV1,RCC_PLLMul_8);
RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);

while(RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY)!=SET);

RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);

RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);
RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);
RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div1);

while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08){} 
    
SystemCoreClockUpdate();
```

}

USART configuration:

```
USAR.USART_BaudRate=115200;
USAR.USART_StopBits=USART_StopBits_1;
USAR.USART_WordLength=USART_WordLength_8b;
USAR.USART_Parity=USART_Parity_No;
USAR.USART_HardwareFlowControl=USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USAR.USART_Mode=USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
USART_Init(USART1,&USAR);

NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_2); 

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART1_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure); 

USART_ITConfig(USART1,USART_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);
USART_Cmd(USART1,ENABLE);
```

Comment: Post the USART initialization too. Have you defined the new crystal speed in the code so the code knows the crystal and system clocks are now different?

Comment: Always use a logic analyzer when debugging such communication problems. It will save you hours & days.

Comment: OK, according to the data sheet USART1 is located on APB2 - You are not dividing that so we should run at 64 MHz and you do call systemcoreclockupdate() - Are you enabling the clock for the USART1 in RCC_APB2ENR ? What does your USART init look like and what does your GPIO look like, also please show us the register content when running the software.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments( Tagli, Sorenp), Justme thank you for your valuable comment, I didn't know to set HSE_VALUE to tell my compiler about the working frequency.

Answer (score 1):

We should define HSE_VALUE for compiler to define our working frequency.